# Spring Webflow: logout

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, spring-webflow, freemarker

I am using Webflow 2.3.0.RELEASE and Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE with Spring security and Freemarker.
It all works well except that when I logout the session is not destroyed.

e.g. when I click the logout link on the screen, I can see the logout screen successfully with url like this:

```
http://localhost/mart/adminflow.html;jsessionid=855454DFGDFG54501DSF548036?execution=e1s1
```

If I copy this url and paste into a new window, it just works with me still logged in.

I am not too sure what code to share, but I can share.

Any advice/

Thanks

UPDATE 1:

The logout link :

```
<a class="link_a" href="../j_spring_security_logout">
```

Security config:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"> 
      <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" /> 
      <security:logout logout-success-url="logout.htm?_eventId=logout" /> 
      <security:session-management invalid-session-url="logout.htm?_eventId=logout" /> 
</security:http>
```

Comment: What does the logout link exactly do? Also, please include your spring security config in the question.

Comment: Hmm, the config looks alright, but the behaviour you describe seems to be in contradiction with your settings. A logout request sent to `/j_spring_security_logout` should be redirected to `logout.htm?_eventId=logout` according to the `logout-success-url` attribute, but you say you landed on `mart/adminflow...`. Something seems to be wrong here. I would suggest enabling debug/trace level logging on the `org.springframework.security.web` package to see what exactly happens upon logout. Post some logs here, if you still have problems.

Comment: No, logout works fine. Problem is when before logout if i copy the url (including the jsessionid) and paste this copied url in a new window (after logging out), it shows that I am still logged in.

Comment: If logout works indeed fine, you'll see a log message emitted by `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` saying `Invalidating session: <sessionId>` (that's the default behavior that you didn't change in your config). Subsequently submitting the same (already invalidated) session id will certainly redirect you to the configured `invalid-session-url` page. Your problem might be that the browser cached the page, and the request doesn't hit the server at all. Check the caching related headers on the http response.